# Where can I find the generic macOS file icon image?

Tags: macos

Historically, you could find a lot of system images in /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources. In macOS 13, these are mostly old.

Are there other locations I'm missing? Ideally I need something on a transparent background so I can use the shadow.

[image: Screenshot of file icon]

Comment: Why isn't `~Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle` not suiting your needs, it still contains good enough .icns images. Could you explain what you really want here?

Comment: *"something on a transparent background"* Why not tell us what the 'something' is, in case someone knows a better way to get it?

Comment: Did you just look for *.icns files? Did you look in Assets.car?